# Xcode: If Statements with textbox

Tags: iphone, text, textbox, alertview

So im having problems do this. This code wont work the way i want it to.

```
if (answer.text == @"text") {
    UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}else{
    UIAlertView  *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title 2" message:@"Title 2" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert1 show];
    [alert1 release];
}
```

My problem is the textbox 'answer' has the text 'text' in it, it wont do the first UIAlertView. It always does the one in the else{}. This code is also in an IBAction for a button. Any help now is good.

Comment: try comparing strings like this: `[answer.text isEqualToString:@"text"]` Also make sure you have outlets correctly connected (`answer` is `IBOutlet`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator only compares pointers, so two identical instances of NSString won't compare equal. Use a comparison method instead:

```
if ([answer.text isEqualToString:@"text"]) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
```

One good note:

In a lot of languages it usually isn't a good idea to use `==` to compare stings. I always look for a compare string function or method. I would advise you do, unless the language manuals say otherwise.

Comment: That's because in a lot of languages variables are just pointers. == is generally pointer comparison.